# Java 3D Canvas To Virtual World Mapping

Tags: java, graphics, java-3d, 3d

I have a 3d Scene set up and can navigate my scene etc (I am fairly experienced in Java 3D) but i still need ways to achive the following four operations in Java 3D:

- map the viewing area of my Canvas3D into the virtual world (with this mapping i should be able to draw an outline (rectangle) in the virtual world around the viewing canvas).
- translate from a mouse point on the canvas to a point in the virtual world (if i have this i should also be able to achieve the above objective)
- translate from a point in the virtual world to a point on the Canvas3D object
- i want to be able to zoom my scene to fit into the viewing area of the Canvas3D object (hopefully without trial and error.  Ie. hopefully without zooming in a little, then testing points again, then repeating)

All of the above are very closely related so any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To convert from Canvas3D coordinates to Virtual world coordinates, you should use the [getVworldToImagePlate](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D.html#getVworldToImagePlate%28javax.media.j3d.Transform3D%29) and [getImagePlateToVworld](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D.html#getImagePlateToVworld%28javax.media.j3d.Transform3D%29) methods of Canvas3D.  That will get you a mapping from imagePlate coordinates to virtual world coordinates.

To convert a pixel location to virtual world coordinates, you need to chain the above transform with the return from [getPixelLocationInImagePlate](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D.html#getPixelLocationInImagePlate%28int,%20int,%20javax.vecmath.Point3d%29)

The reverse of the above, [getPixelLocationFromImagePlate](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/javax/media/j3d/Canvas3D.html#getPixelLocationFromImagePlate%28javax.vecmath.Point3d,%20javax.vecmath.Point2d%29), will answer your third point.

One you have everything in the same coordinate space, you can start figuring out the proper transformations that you need for your specific application.